# A question about the CE amplifier

Tags: phase-shift, common-emitter

Note: I'm asking this question for a friend. I'm not into Electricity, but I will show him the answers.

What is the relation between the frequency and the phase shift in a common emitter amplifier. Is it always a 180 degrees shift whatever the frequency is?

Comment: So why doesn't your friend ask himself?

Comment: Seriously, asking here is very easy. Tell your friend she/he should ask! You can still help with language, formatting, spelling... But it's pretty stupid to let someone else ask if that someone doesn't have the same level of understanding

Comment: I understand your point. Anyway, I'm sorry and thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In its simplest form a CE amplifier is simply one small current controlling another larger current. That larger current is passed through a resistor which, thanks to Ohm's Law, drops a predictable voltage. It's that voltage drop that is seen on the output as the waveform.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftwuks.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

An increase in \$Vb\$ causes an increase in current through the base (set by \$Re\$). That increase in current through the base causes an increase in current through the collector. That means an increase in current through \$Rc\$. An increase in current through a resistor results in an increase in the voltage dropped across the resistor - so the voltage at \$Vo\$ goes down.

Similarly, a decrease in \$Vb\$ means a decrease in the base current which means a decrease in the collector current which means a decrease in the voltage dropped by \$Rc\$, so \$Vo\$ rises.

As you can see there is a direct inversion there - an increase in \$Vb\$ means a decrease in \$Vo\$ and a decrease in \$Vb\$ means an increase in \$Vo\$.

That can be equated to a 180° phase shift if the signal is a pure sine. If it's anything else then it's a signal inversion, not a phase shift (a phase shift is basically a delay in the signal. There is no delay here, only an inversion of the voltages).

At higher frequencies the time taken for the change in \$Vb\$ to be transferred to \$Vo\$ starts to play a part, which is then seen as a phase shift (the *Miller Capacitance* that @Andy aka mentions).

Answer (score 3):

A CE amplifier inverts the signal at the input; it doesn't phase shift it although, having said that, if the input signal were a sinewave, it would look like the CE amplifier produced a 180 degress phase shift.

Miller capacitance eventually turns a CE amplifier into a kind of integrator and this happens at the higher frequencies thus an inverter (180 degrees) becomes an integrator (90 degrees).

Comment: Point being that of Fourier is right, you can decompose any signal into a sum of (infinitely, uncountably) many sinusoidal oscillations, and an inverter is a 180° phase shift for every single one of these...